# how to access json object from angular service

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, json

I have some module and method loginUSer in login.js as follows:

```
...function loginUser(){
      var user={
          email:loginVM.Email,
          password:loginVM.pwd
      };

      console.log(user);

      loginService.loginCheck()
        .then(...
```

I have loginService injected to the above module

```
function loginService($q, $http){
    var self = this;

    self.loginCheck = loginCheck;

    function loginCheck(){
        var defer = $q.defer();
        $http
            .post(someURL)
            .data(user)
            .then(successFN, errorFN);
```

I want to access the user object that I created in login.js from loginService.js. I am creating user object on my submit button click and calling the service. I have included both the JS in my HTML file.

I think user is getting treated as local var to the loginUser function.
How shall I do that?

Comment: What JSON? You seem to have a regular object there. http://benalman.com/news/2010/03/theres-no-such-thing-as-a-json/

Comment: ```var user``` is a javascript object. Not a JSON object. Can you pass the ```user``` object into the service when you call ```loginCheck()?```. For example: ```loginService.loginCheck(user).then(....```

Answer (score 0):

I have a separate module that designates my loaded resources. I can read/write to them. Simply inject the module into the same app as your service and then use them directly. For instance...

```
angular.module('app.resources', [])
    .value('stuff', {
        login: {
            userName: null,
            otherProperty: foo
        }
    })
```

That maintains state, so you can inject it into another module or, if the rest of your app is using the same service...the values are always available.

Comment: Hey 
I am totally new to angular. Can you please provide some additional examples or references that I could refer to?
and I already have a module declared a module in login.js

Comment: well, if you just want to append to your existing module, you can omit the array brackets when declaring the above module and use the same name as your existing module...eg (angular.module('app').value('stuff', {...}) --> the nice part of this is that angular will load it in the proper sequence and you can use the 'value provider' anywhere within your module.